# I have two excel sheets with mismatched lists and need to map values from one to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have this formula so far but can't figure out how to make it reference the matched cell and replace it with an adjacent value.

Example images in a fresh sheet below, the real one is more complicated.

[image]

```
=IF(INDEX(DATA!R1C1:DATA!R2C1, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(RC[-1], DATA!R1C1:DATA!R2C1), 0)),DATA!R1C2, 999)
```

I've tried a few other functions but that one works the best I think.

```
=INDEX(R2C1:R102C1, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(RC[1],"*"&R2C1:R102C1&"*"), 0))

=INDEX(DATA!R1C1:DATA!R103C1, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(RC[1],"*"&DATA!R1C1:DATA!R103C1&"*"), 0))

=IF(OR(COUNTIF(RC[1],"*"DATA!R[1]C[1]:DATA!R[103]C[1]&"*")), "Yes", "No")

=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(COUNTIF(RC[1], "*"&DATA!R[1]C[1]:DATA!R[103]C[1]&"*"), DATA!R[1]C[1]:DATA!R[103]C[1], ""))
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do. Can you clarify, with expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have two sheets, both have a product identifier and a price but on one the price is wrong, I need to map the correct price over the incorrect one, but the lists are in not exactly the same (more products on one, I have duplicate values on the other) so I cant just sort each list the same and copy the correct price over. I need to map it based on the identifier. The example screenshots are quite simplified

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` and `INDEX/MATCH` won't work? What errors are you getting? I am unsure, as the post is rather hard to understand, but I think you're doing too much?  Can you post a more simple "example input" and "example output"?

Comment: Perhaps give us an example of what you're expecting the output to look like.  The two images don't really explain why the 3 becomes 5, for instance.

Comment: I've added a new image hopefully explaining the situation a bit better!

Comment: `=vlookup(A2, Data!A:B, 2, False)` ?

Comment: It feels like you could just use an index/match formula to do what i think you're trying to do.  your attempt at the index/match formula isnt well written. you should replace the 1 after the match with the cell that has the identifier you want to match, and the countif expression should just be the array where the items that match your identifiers exist. Something like this should be sufficient
=INDEX(DATA!$B$1:$B$10, MATCH(FINALSHEET!A1, DATA!$A$1:$A$10), 0))

Comment: `=INDEX(DATA!R1C2:DATA!R102C2,MATCH(RC1,DATA!R1C1:R102C1,0),)` ? or `=VLOOKUP(RC1,DATA!R1C1:DATA!R102C2,2,0)`

Comment: In your 'Final' sheet, column 1 contains static and unique SKUs, column 2 is formulated to look up the most current prices from the 'DATA' sheet based on the SKU in Column 1, using VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP will do the job. In your 'DATA' sheet, you need to update the price list regularly with the most current prices and delete the old prices. Alternatively, you can keep adding new prices to the list, but you need to use the XLOOKUP formula to search for the latest price from last to first in the list. Trust this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the values you want it to be returning and match your Column 1 values against the Column 1 values in Sheet `Data`.

`=INDEX(DATA!R1C2:DATA!R102C2,MATCH(RC1,DATA!R1C1:R102C1,0),)`

or which is useful in this case (2 columns lookup offset to the right):

`=VLOOKUP(RC1,DATA!R1C1:DATA!R102C2,2,0)`

I must say your examples are a little confusing. You mention *previous values* that do not match any of the given screenshots.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the confusion, I think partly because the original formula was actually to pull out the identifier from a url in the sheet.